# How get Date from string and How confront two date

Tags: jquery, date

I need to confront two date and I have two string that are in the dd-mm-yyyy format. Now I  need to transform in a date so:

```
    var string_date1= //in dd-mm-yyyy
    string_date1=string_date1.split('-');
    var date1=new Date(string_date[0],parseInt(string_date[1]),string_date[2]);
var date2=// the same think with the second string
```

But when I print date1.toString() I read another date.Anyone can help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "confront two dates"? Do you need to convert perhaps? if so, which format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order of parameters is incorrect for `new Date()`

They should be

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

But you are doing

```
new Date(day, month, year)
```

Also note that `month` is zero index based so you need to subtract `1` from human readable value

Reference [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)